# GCP Logs: How to query within an array of objects (regex like)

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

Let's say I have logs that look like :

```json
{
  jsonPayload: {
    anArray: [
      {
        someField: 10000
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In my GCP log query, I want to query something like:

```
jsonPayload.anArray.*.someField > 1000
```

Of course, the query above is incorrect, but I'd like to know if its possible to query for any item in the array of objects which has a someField value above 1000.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Let us say you have a data structure that looks like this:

```
{
  "message":{
    "message1":[
      {
        "value":950
      },
      {
        "value":2000
      },
      {
        "value":1200
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In Logs Explorer, you can run the query below and return the whole `JsonPayload` if at least 1 object in it satisfies the condition value > 1000 . This query follows the logic `950 > 1000 OR 9 > 1000 OR 1200 > 1000`. You can read more about the querying in the [Querying Logging docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language#object_array_types).

```
resource.type="global"
jsonPayload.message.message1.value > 1000
```

I have another `JsonPayload` entry that has a value of 5000 and is only the lone value for that entry. Thus returning both entries.

Result:

[image]